# LibGDX Lightmap framebuffer does not include ambient light setting

Tags: libgdx, box2d, lighting

Ambient light is set to `0.5` which is visible in the game but if I try to capture the light map frame buffer there is clearly no ambient light information, the lights are at maximum brightness and the dark areas are fully black when they should in fact be grey.

```
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(cam);
rayHandler.update();
rayHandler.prepareRender();

lightMap = new TextureRegion(rayHandler.getLightMapTexture());
lightMap.flip(false, true);

batch.begin();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(screenMatrix);
batch.draw(lightMap, game.getViewport().getScreenX(), game.getViewport().getScreenY(),
    game.getViewport().getScreenWidth(), game.getViewport().getScreenHeight());
batch.end();
```

[image]

EDIT: Even weirder, I found this out 100% by accident since it doesn't appear to make sense. If I run `rayHandler.prepareRender();` twice, it renders the lightmap correctly..

```
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(cam);
rayHandler.update();
rayHandler.prepareRender();
rayHandler.prepareRender();//twice
```

The light source probably doesn't have the same settings as before so appears brighter but we can see the ambient light is definitely 0.5 since it is grey like it should be.

[image]

Comment: Depending on whether you have shadows and/or diffuse settings turned on in RayHandler, the colors are encoded differently into the texture. See the docs for `RayHandler.diffuseBlendFunc`, `shadowBlendFunc`, and `simpleBlendFunc` to know which type of blending you should use when rendering the texture.

Comment: @Tenfour04 There's no texture or blending, this is just the lightmap alone.

Comment: I'm saying the lightmap will be encoded differently depending on those settings, so it may not appear the way you are expecting.

Comment: @Tenfour04 There's no way to blend it correctly, no matter what blending mode you use the ambient light will never be 0.5 since the dark parts are 100% black...the lightmap itself is fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Check my updated question...the weirdest thing in the world fixes it but I've no idea why it should work like that..